# TouchScreen : How to get max touch points programmatically

Tags: touch, touch-event

It seems touchscreen comes with varying Touch Point capabilities i.e. 5 Touch Points, 10 Touch Points or 20 Touch Points.

Is there a way to get supported Touch Points programmatically instead of hard coding it for Windows OS.

In the application ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/detecting-and-tracking-multiple-touch-points)) max touch point is hard coded to the following:
#define MAXPOINTS 10

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/detecting-and-tracking-multiple-touch-points

I went through the MSDN [touch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.touch?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) documentation but could not find a relevant API.